# Modeling integers in NLP

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, integer-programming

I was wondering why it is not OK to model binary (integer) variables of an optimization problem, in the following form

```
x(x-1) = 0
```

What are the consequences for an NLP (solved with IP)?
Isn't it better to avoid converting an NLP problem to an MINLP?
What are the other modeling options available (not decomposition)?

Comment: It would be great if you could share your experience on this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice that does not work very well. The problem is that this introduces a nasty non-convexity. Also if this would really be a good idea then we would not need MINLP solvers (or even MIP solvers) at all. All the effort to develop those solvers would have been wasted.

Comment: Erwin, I agree with you. I am not in favor of this approach as I have tried it and it didn't work the way it should. But, the function f(x) = x^2 - x is a convex function. Isn't it? Could you please explain more on the introduction of a "nasty non-convexity"?

Comment: But as equality constraint it is non-convex. Any nonlinear equality constraint is non-convex. You can also argue $x=0$ or $x=1$ is non-convex as all values in between are not allowed.

Comment: Thanks for following up Erwin. Would it mean that converting this equality constraint to an inequality constraint, i.e. -ε<x(x-1)<ε and minimize ε with a penalty factor will lead to avoiding the non-convexity?

Comment: No. That is also non-convex.